# Vim Split window when opening multiple files

Tags: vim

I would like to put something into my vimrc so that if I open 2 files they automatically open in separate split windows. I don't want to start it with `-o` because I sometimes open a lot of files at once and having 15+ splits would not work very good. so I would like some logic that checks how many files were open and if it is 2 to put each one into its own split window.

Thanks

PS I will most likely use this most often to view the .cc and .hh files of a c++ project.

Comment: and is there a way to close those 15 [unedited] windows simultaneously, afterwards?

Comment: sure. quit all will close all open windows  

    :qa!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add

```
if argc() == 2
  silent all
endif
```

to your .vimrc.

Comment: That works great except for one thing, I get a `Press ENTER or type command to continue` is there any way to avoid that prompt?. thanks

Comment: Any chance that there's a way to change this to a vertical split? ie -O instead of -o?

Comment: @Leihca Change `all` to `vertical all`. It’s all there in the manual.

Answer (score 4):

I accomplish the same thing, from the command-line alone, by adding to my vim command `-c 'split | bn'`.  I can open as many files as I like in the same command; `-c` tells it to run a command, then in the single-quotes, `'split | bn'` tells vim to split the window, then switch to the next buffer.  So if I type, for example:

```
gvim foo1.cpp foo2.cpp foo3.cpp foo4.cpp -c 'split | bn'
```

Then gvim opens with the first two files, foo1.cpp and foo2.cpp, in the split windows.  I like this way because I don't have to modify my .vimrc (so I can use it on any machine), and it's still concise enough for the command-line.

Note: I've only tested this in gvim, not vim in a terminal.

Comment: That's trippy, but same question must be asked: can it be made into a vertical split?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

```
vim -o2 file1 file2 file3...
```

I know it isn't perfect solution to you (in this case vim opens everytime two windows).

But you can write (and use) a small script like this

```
if [ $# -ge 2 ];
    vim -o2 $*
else
    vim $*
fi
```

Almost perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps could set up something in shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$#" -eq "2" ]]
then
  /usr/bin/vim -o $1 $2 
else
  /usr/bin/vim $*
fi
```

If you are feeling a bit fancy then you could do something more complex, by looping through the parameters and checking if any are options and ignoring them.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way but would rather have it in my vimrc. If I don't get any other ideas I'll accept that one. Thanks